# IIS7 Rewrite Rule to redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I want the following to redirect to `https://www.domain.com`

- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

I used the default rules in IIS for the canonical domain redirect, which uses this pattern :

`^www\.domain\.com$`

This works fine for the first one. The `www` domain does not redirect. I tried removing the `^` but that doesnt work. How do I fix this?

Comment: If only there was some domain explicitly reserved for examples... Oh, wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have URL-Rewrite module on IIS7?

Typical example for HTTP to HTTPS redirection:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Can you try?

Comment: Alone, it works only for www. I then added the default canonical redirect and it works for both. thanks